# How to make divs invisible from javascript for?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have the next code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
      // div[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
      //div[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>WebSite</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    #networdapp {
      display: none;
    }
    
    #myInput {
      background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
      background-position: 10px 12px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    
    #myUL {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    #myUL li a {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-top: -1px;
      /* Prevent double borders */
      background-color: #f6f6f6;
      padding: 12px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: black;
      display: block
    }
    
    #myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
      background-color: #eee;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name" type="search" placeholder="Search">
  </form>

  <div id="test" class="networdapp">
    <div class="container" id="test2">
      <ul id="myUL">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="networdapp">
          <div class="row">
            <div v-for="result in results" class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="card m-3 h-240  bg-light">
                <div class="card-header text-center">
                  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body" style="height:200px">
                  <p class="card-text" v-html="result.prevDesc"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer bg-transparent border-info">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Details</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="test" class="networdapp">
          <div class="container" id="test2">
            <ul id="myUL">
              <div class="container-fluid" id="networdapp">
                <div class="row">
                  <div v-for="result in results" class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="card m-3 h-240  bg-light">
                      <div class="card-header text-center">
                        <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
                      </div>
                      <div class="card-body" style="height:200px">
                        <p class="card-text" v-html="result.prevDesc"></p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="card-footer bg-transparent border-info">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Details</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div id="test" class="networdapp">
                <div class="container" id="test2">
                  <ul id="myUL">
                    <div class="container-fluid" id="networdapp">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div v-for="result in results" class="col-sm-6">
                          <div class="card m-3 h-240  bg-light">
                            <div class="card-header text-center">
                              <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body" style="height:200px">
                              <p class="card-text" v-html="result.prevDesc"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer bg-transparent border-info">
                              <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Details</a>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="test" class="networdapp">
                      <div class="container" id="test2">
                        <ul id="myUL">
                          <div class="container-fluid" id="networdapp">
                            <div class="row">
                              <div v-for="result in results" class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="card m-3 h-240  bg-light">
                                  <div class="card-header text-center">
                                    <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="card-body" style="height:200px">
                                    <p class="card-text" v-html="result.prevDesc"></p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="card-footer bg-transparent border-info">
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Details</a>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

What I want to do is to display some divs depending on the input from that input box.What I've done so far is to display only the "li" tags but what I actually want is to display the entire div not only the "li" depending on the input data the divs must be displayed or not.
Shown above is my code right now.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: if you are using vueJS, check https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

Comment: You do not have valid HTML. Some closing tags are missing. Also li should be a direct child of ul.

Comment: Is just a snippet of my code,i modifed it when i asked this questions and i forgot some tags,my apologies.Anyway,Thank you for help,both of you!

Comment: There are multiple IDs that are in there several times (#myUL, #test2, #networdapp). Each ID must be unique in the document

Answer (score 0):

While you are showing your "LI", there you can show it's parent DIV by using "parentElement". Please check below snippet.

Your code

```
li[i].style.display = "none";
li[i].style.display = "";
```

New Code

```
li[i].parentElement.style.display = "none";
li[i].parentElement.style.display = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should tidy up your html with respect of the repeated IDs and the `<li>`s not being direct children if `<ul>`.

Having done that @Ambuj Khanna's advice should be helpful. You might have to apply `parentElement` repeatedly.

It occurred to me that the whole operation is something that could have been done using jQuery in two lines:

```
var flt=$('#myInput').val().toUpperCase();
$('#myUl>div').each(function(i,div){$(div).toggle($('li',div).text().toUpperCase()==flt)})
```

The above should make the top level divs - just below your `<ul#myUl>` - visible and hide all others. However, the element below a `<ul>` should always be a `<li>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for help!Problem solved now.I just used a JQuery parser for div and everything worked pretty well.